# High Altitude Nitro

Tags: carbonation, pressure, force-carbonation

I recently relocated to Denver and found some excellent advice in [this question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3680/brewing-at-altitude) but I was wondering since drj mentioned that since carbonation is an issue how that will affect my nitro setup and carbing?

My current process is to carb (using CO2) to about 7-8psi and then switch to beergas(75/25) that I set to 32-33psi. Will this need to be altered?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The carbonation process shouldn't matter with respect to your altitude.  Inside your keg is a closed system. So the same rules of temperature and pressure applied will get you the same volumes of CO2.

The rate at which the beer 'de-carbs' in the glass IS effected by your altitude however. So if you find that the beer is getting too flat to quickly, well then maybe you want to up your carbonation volume by 10% until it seems right.